Problem with a matplotlib figure and its toolbar inside a tkinter notebook
I'm creating a GUI and inside this one I have a notebook embedded in a paned window.
Inside this notebook, i created 2 tab and I create for each one of them a matplotlib figure with its toolbar.
However for the second tab, the toolbar is located outside of the paned window and I need to resize it to see the toolbar. In comparison, when I resize the first tab I always have the figure and its toolbar whatever the size of the paned window.
I am a beginner on tkinter and in GUI creation, I would really appreciate your help !
Here is my class which create the GUI :
os.chdir(absolute_path+toolbox_path_graph)
from graph_window import graph_window
os.chdir(absolute_path)

class Project(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         
         #Set-up Window
         self.title("Title")
         self.state('zoomed')
         
         #Default dimensions of the paned windows
         self.dim_paned_windows=({"height":700},{"width":600})

         #Create the paned windows
         self.paned_windows()

         self.graph_window_instance=graph_window(np ,tk, ttk, self.graph)
         
        
     def paned_windows(self):
         #1st Paned windows
         panel_1=tk.PanedWindow(bd=2, relief="groove", bg="gray")
         panel_1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
         
         #1st window
         self.paned_window1=tk.Label(panel_1,takefocus=0,highlightthickness=0)
         panel_1.add(self.paned_window1, width=600)
         
         #2nd Paned window
         self.panel_2=tk.PanedWindow(panel_1,bd=0, orient=tk.VERTICAL,relief="groove", bg="gray")
         panel_1.add(self.panel_2)
         
         #Graph window
         self.graph=tk.Canvas(self.panel_2, bg="white", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, takefocus=0)
         self.panel_2.add(self.graph,height=700)    

         #3rd window
         self.paned_window3=tk.Label(self.panel_2)
         self.panel_2.add(self.paned_window3)
         
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = Project()
     app.mainloop()





Here is my class for which create the figures :
class graph_window:
    def __init__(self, np, tk, ttk, master_frame): #master_frame=paned window
        #Add modules
        self.np=np
        self.tk=tk
        self.ttk=ttk

        #Define list for different graph
        self.graph=[]
        self.fig=[]
        self.ax=[]
        self.toolbar=[]
        
        #Main
        self.main(master_frame)
        
        
    def main(self, master_frame):
        #Create the tabs
        self.tab1, self.tab2=self.setup_tab(master_frame)
        self.setup_graph(self.tab2)
        self.setup_graph(self.tab1)
        
    def setup_tab(self, master_frame):
        #Define style to position the tab at the bottom left
        style=self.ttk.Style(master_frame)
        style.configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='sw')
        
        #Creation of the tab control
        tabControl=self.ttk.Notebook(master_frame, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
        tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill=self.tk.BOTH)
        
        #Creation of the tab
        tab1=self.ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tab2=self.ttk.Frame(tabControl)
         
        #Set the name of the tab
        tabControl.add(tab1, text='tab1')
        tabControl.add(tab2, text='tab2')

        return tab1, tab2
        

    def setup_graph(self, tab_frame):
        fig, ax=plt.subplots()
        
        self.fig.append(fig)
        self.ax.append(ax)

        #Create Matplotlib graph
        self.graph.append(FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig[-1], master=tab_frame))
        self.graph[-1].get_tk_widget().pack(expand=True, fill=self.tk.BOTH)
        
        #Create toolbar
        self.toolbar.append(NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.graph[-1], tab_frame, pack_toolbar=False))
        self.toolbar[-1].update()
        self.toolbar[-1].pack()
    
        #Define axis system and title
        self.ax[-1].set_xlabel('a')
        self.ax[-1].set_ylabel('b')
        self.ax[-1].set_title('title')
        
        #Define default scale 
        self.ax[-1].set_xlim(0,160)
        self.ax[-1].set_ylim(0,100)


Here are the screenshots obtained at the launch of the GUI.
tab1
tab2
Here is what I obtain after resizing the paned windown:
tab2 by default
tab2 after resizing
the toolbar only appears in tab2 if the window is enough big, which is not the same behavior than tab1.
I tried to switch to the grid method, but I didn't manage to obtain the same result than the one in tab1.

Cannot reproduce the issue after adding missing parts to code to make it a [mre].  Using Python 3.12.3 and matplotlib 3.8.4 in Windows 11.  Also it is strange to pass modules to a class initialization code.

Note that if master_frame is an instance of PanedWindow, you should use master_frame.add(tabControl) instead of tabControl.pack(...) to put the notebook into the paned window.

Hello @acw1668, I added my class which create the GUI, you should be able to launch it I think. I tried master_frame.add(tabControl), but I got the following error : 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'add'. Also I'm using python 3.11.8 and Matplotlib 3.8.

Then master_frame is not paned window as said in the code comment.

I don't understand why you use Canvas instead of Frame as the master_frame.  Also cannot reproduce the issue with your updated code. Note that bottom argument in the function definition graph_window.__init__() should be removed because it is not given when instance is created.

@acw1668, Indeed using Frame make more sense, I will modify that but it doesn't affect the issue. I don't understand why you can't launch the GUI, when I copy the code and paste it in python it works for me (I deleted bottom).

I said I cannot reproduce the issue, not cannot launch the GUI.

So for both tab the toolbar is packed perfectly, well I will try on Python 3.12.3 and Matplotlib 3.8.4 maybe it will fix it.

This is the image for tab1, and this is for tab2.

I tried Python 3.12.3 and Matplotlib 3.8.4 and the issue is still there.  @acw1668 You seems to have the good behavior.  I added picture from my GUI in the original post.

So, I was able to reduce the perimeter of the problem after removing the toolbar. It appears that the problem comes from the size of the canvas containing the figure.
Here the result I obtain after removing the toolbars.
tab1 default
tab2 default
When FigureCanvasTkAgg is called, it creates the event self._tkcanvas.bind("<Map>", self._update_device_pixel_ratio) inside _backend_tk.py.
The function _update_device_pixel_ratio seems to change the size of the canvas
the shape value obtained.
For now, I have been able to temporarily fix the problem by preventing the if test : if self._set_device_pixel_ratio(ratio): to be done for the tab2 event.
But this requires changing the code in backend_bases.py and I don't want my users to change the libraries.
